# Angular 6 - nested Firebase requests

Tags: angular, firebase

I have the code below:

Shifts depend on locations, locations depend on cities and 
`this.getCities()`, `this.getEmployerLocations()` and `this.getEmployerShifts()`calls return `Observables`

```
export class Employer {

cities      : string[];
locations   : Location[];
shifts      : Sift[];

constructor() {

    this.prepareShifts();

}

this.prepareShifts() {

}

this.getCities().subscribe( cities => {

    this.cities = cities;

    this.getEmployerLocations().subscribe( locations => {

        this.locations = locations;

        this.locations.forEach( location => {

            location.city = this.getCityById( location.cityId ); // from cities received: this.cities

        }); 

        this.getEmployerShifts().subscribe( shifts => {

            this.shifts = shifts;

            thi.shifts.forEach( shift => {

                this.shift.location = this.getShiftLocationById( shift.locationId );  // from locations received: this.locations

            });                 
        });                         
    );          
});
}
```

As you can see I need to fill out cities, locations and shifts by values from Firebase. And I did nested calls to achieve the goal.

I wonder is there a proper way to have it done? I have a feeling I do it wrong.

Comment: Did you check `async` `await` syntax of javascript ?

Comment: or `switchMap` in rxjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` operator of `RxJs`.

It is great for nested async operations. There are some other similar operators, `flatMap` is the one I usually use. When you use `flatMap`, it is just like `map` operator in which you return a scalar object. With `flatMap` you return another observable. At the end, you can subscribe to the latest observable.

Here is how you can do it

```js
import { flatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.getCities().pipe(
   flatMap(cities => {
       this.cities = cities;
       return this.getEmployerLocations();
   }),
   flatMap(locations => {
      this.locations = locations;
      this.locations.forEach( location => {
          location.city = this.getCityById( location.cityId ); // from cities received: this.cities    
      }); 
      return this.getEmployerShifts();
   })
).subscribe(shifts => {
      this.shifts = shifts;
      this.shifts.forEach( shift => {
          this.shift.location = this.getShiftLocationById( shift.locationId );  // from locations received: this.locations
      });                     
});
```